# V3 Healthcare Finder API Schema Broken?

Tags: healthcare-finder-api

I'm attempting to generate a C# class from the [V3 schema](https://finder.healthcare.gov/api/finder_api_v3.0.xsd) and it's failing on a long list of "type not declared" errors.  I tried validating the schema in Altova MapForce and it throws the following error:

Unable to load schema with target namespace 'http://hios.cms.org/api-types' from 'hios-api-type-11.0.xsd'

At this point I'm not sure if there is a problem with V3 schema or if the namespace it references is missing or if I'm doing something wrong.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

We had no issues with this approach with the V2 schema.